# Multiple hypothesis testing of interactions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, modeling, interaction, multiple-comparisons

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(1:100), b=runif(1:100), c=runif(1:100), d=runif(1:100), e=runif(1:100), f=runif(1:100))
```

I would like to model multiple interactions of the effect of b on c, b on d, b on e, and b on f.

What is the difference between specifying a single model with all interactions and their main effect.

```
summary(lm(a ~ b * (c + d + e + f), data = df))
```

and specifying individual interactions in multiple models.

```
summary(lm(a ~ b*c + d + e + f, data = df))
summary(lm(a ~ c + b*d + e + f, data = df))
summary(lm(a ~ c + d + b*e + f, data = df))
summary(lm(a ~ c + d + e + b*f, data = df))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

EDIT:

I'm interested in which method is the correct method of testing for significant interactions between B and the other covariates.

I'm currently testing each interaction independently and then correcting for multiple comparisons via bonferroni. However would the first method of specifying a single model with all of the interaction terms provide the same information ?

Comment: If you use a real dataset, and check the model matrix, it will most likely become clear. For instance, compare: `model.matrix(lm(mpg ~ wt * disp + hp + drat, mtcars))` to `model.matrix(lm(mpg ~ wt * (disp + hp + drat), mtcars))`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I'm actually interested in regards to which method is the proper method of testing the effect interaction between b and the other covariates. I was specifying my model one by one as the second method, and then correcting the p value using bonferroni correction for multiple comparisons. However, I was wondering if specifying all of the interactions in a single model as the first method would accomplish the same thing